# unable to Pass FirefoxProfile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file

Tags: java, selenium, mutablecapabilities

```
public class download {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/ranjith/Downloads/geckodriver");
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/home/ranjith/Downloads");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");        
        profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
        profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 

        driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test File to Download")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //driver.close();
    }
}
```

asking to remove argument profile to match FirefoxDriver in eclipse
can you help to sort out this problem.

Error is thrown on this line

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Hi Ranjith please mention what you need and what are you are trying to achieve since there is no constructor which accepts custom class as parameter  in FireFoxDriver class

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriver.htm thats why you are facing that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *Selenium JavaDoc* of *FirefoxDriver* Class, `FirefoxDriver(profile)` method is no more supported as a valid `Constructor`.

Instead it is being encouraged to use the `FirefoxOptions` Class which extends `MutableCapabilities` i.e. **`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`**

So as you are creating a new *FirefoxProfile* on each execution through `driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`, you have to use the `setProfile()` method from the *FirefoxOptions* Class which is defined as :

```
public FirefoxOptions setProfile(FirefoxProfile profile)
```

Your code block will be :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/ranjith/Downloads/geckodriver");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/home/ranjith/Downloads");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");        
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.setProfile(profile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

Comment: Clear your `Browser Cache`, Run `CCleaner` tool  to wipe off all the OS chores. Take a `System Restart` and run the `Test` and let me know the status.

Comment: I am actually trying to download a file using selenium webdriver. now it's working after resolving all issues