# Selenium webdriver opening default firefox profile instead of predefined profile

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

How do I get Selenium webdriver to open Firefox with a predefined profile instead of the default profile?

the below code opens firefox with default profile

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to Pass FirefoxProfile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568275/unable-to-pass-firefoxprofile-parameter-in-webdriver-to-use-preferences-to-downl)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954682/setting-selenium-to-use-custom-profile-but-it-keeps-opening-with-default