# In Selenium Java client what is the difference between addArguments and setPreference methods?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

When using Java and Selenium, frequently when I google how to change a certain behaviour I find some example that explains how to change a setting using either addArgument or set_preferences, something like this:

```
    options.addArguments("dom.webdriver.enabled=False");
    options.addArguments("useAutomationExtension=False");
    
    profile.setPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False);
    profile.setPreference("useAutomationExtension", False);
```

Looking at the Javadoc isn't very helful:

[image: addArguments Javadoc]

[image: setPreference Javadoc]

Could someone explain the relation between these? Any conceptual differences? They seem very overlapping.

Furthermore, there is `desiredCapabilities` and `capabilities` that also seems very similar. Why do these exist and how do they relate to each other?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences

preferences are settings that are used to control the browser behavior , full list of supported preferences could be found at :

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7e762c1f17514a29834506860961ba2f24e7e6e5/components/content_settings/core/common/pref_names.cc

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Arguments are commands that can be passed as command line arguments to the chrome binary eg

```
chrome.exe --headless
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumOptions.html#addArguments(java.lang.String...)

full list: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

For Firefox:

Arguments : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Add all settings within the Firefox config (which you can access by typing about:config in the address bar) can be set using options.addPreference

Answer (score 0):

### addArguments()

[`addArguments()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#addArguments(java.lang.String...)) is the method to configure the AbstractDriverOptions to manage the firefox specific settings in a way that geckodriver can understand using an instance of [FirefoxOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) Class.

As an example:

```
FirefoxOptions option=new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

### setPreference()

[`setPreference()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) is the method to configure the firefox profile specific settings in a way that geckodriver can understand using an instance of [FirefoxProfile](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) Class.

As an example:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/home/ranjith/Downloads");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Cannot resolve constructor FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof/49686604#49686604)
- [unable to Pass FirefoxProfile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568275/unable-to-pass-firefoxprofile-parameter-in-webdriver-to-use-preferences-to-downl/47569170#47569170)